# How to get Group/Grouping ID from Moodle 1.9

Tags: php, mysql, moodle

I would like to get a Group/Grouping ID from Moodle for a customization of the UI of a course. I need to show Resources to specific Groups/Groupings. I've already got it set up Moodle. I've logged in as different users was able to only access the Resources assigned to that user's group.

My theme has a custom sidebar menu with links to Pages, Assignments and all other Resources to users for that course.  I need to display the correct Resources to a user in the menu using a PHP if/else statement depending on the value of the Group/Grouping ID. I've found some documentation on Moodle.com. I came up with this code that breaks my theme.

```
<?php 
        // Get the course module id from a post or get request.
        $id = required_param('id', PARAM_INT); 

        // Get the course module. 
        $cm = get_coursemodule_from_id('forum', $id, 0, false, MUST_EXIST)

        // Get the current group id.
        $currentgroupingid = groups_get_activity_grouping($cm);


        switch($currentgroupingid) {
            case "1":
                echo "Group 1";
            break;
            case "2":
                echo "Group 2";
            break;
            case "3":
                echo "Group 3";
            break;
            default:
            break;
        }?>
```

This code doesn't work and I'm not sure why. In the documentation there are example on how to access information about Groups and Groupings. [Moodle Group API](http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Groups_API)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my Moodle Course there are three different Groups. I needed the ability to dynamically change the a href of a link on a webpage resource based on a User's Group Enrollment Key. This is what I did:

---

```
<div class="enrolment-key" style="display:none;">
<?php
    // Grab current User's group from Database By ID
    $sqlGROUPMEMBERS = "SELECT * FROM mdl_groups_members WHERE userid='$USER->id'";

    // Put Query in new Varible
    $resultGROUPMEMBERS = mysql_query($sqlGROUPMEMBERS);

    // While $row = group id of user
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultGROUPMEMBERS)){
        $groupID = $row["groupid"];
    }

    // Grab Enrolment Key by the Group ID
    $sqlGROUP = "SELECT * FROM mdl_groups WHERE id=$groupID";

    // Put Query in new Varible
    $resultENROLMENTKEY = mysql_query($sqlGROUP);

    // While $row = group enrolment key for that user
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultENROLMENTKEY)){
        echo $row["enrolmentkey"];
    }
?>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var baseURL = "https://www.surveymonkey.com/s/";
var endURL = $('.enrolment-key').html();

$(".survey-link").attr("href", baseURL + endURL);
 });
 </script>
<a class="survey-link">Link</a>
```

There probably is a better way to do this, but its fine for a Noob like me.